# Android looping through onlinedatabase

Tags: android, database, while-loop

When i'm trying to loop through the database, my activity hang up and nothing happen.

```
    final JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    while (i < jArray.length()) {
        JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        title.setText(json.getString("PhoneName"));
        price.setText("Price : " + json.getString("PhonePrice"));
        modelnumber.setText(json.getString("ModelNumber"));
        arrowfront.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                i++;
            }
        });
        arrowback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                i--;
            }
        });
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("tag", e.toString());
}
}
```

i'm trying to connect to the database, at first the textviews display the firstitem, then when i click on arrow i want to display the second row of the table and so on.. But when the activity launch, it hangs up and nothing happens even that i don't receive error's in logcat
And in the logcat, "tag" doesn't appear. Any suggestion??

Comment: Your onClickListeners must be outside of while loop, thats why your app hangs. Inside while loop parse JSON objects, put results in some kind of list and iterate through it outside of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, do it this way :

```
final JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> resultList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
int position=0;

for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
HashMap<String,String> hm= new HashMap<String,String>();
JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
hm.put("title",json.getString("PhoneName"));
hm.put("price","Price : " + json.getString("PhonePrice"));
hm.put("modelNumber",json.getString("ModelNumber"));
resultList.add(hm);
}

arrowfront.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                position++;
HashMap <String,String> frontHm = new HashMap <String,String>();
frontHm=resultList.get(position);
        title.setText(frontHM.get("title");
        price.setText(frontHM.get("price"));
        modelnumber.setText(frontHM.get("modelNumber"));
            }
        });

arrowback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                position--;
HashMap <String,String> backHm = new HashMap <String,String>();
backHm=resultList.get(position);
        title.setText(backHM.get("title");
        price.setText(backHM.get("price"));
        modelnumber.setText(backHM.get("modelNumber"));
            }
        });
```

So idea is to keep tracking the position inside global "position" variable. Also I didn't add logic inside click listeners to check first and last position because you can not go out of bounds of arraylist, please do it yourself.